# i try to allocated with realloc function and get error

Tags: c, struct, while-loop, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

```
typedef struct{
   char** strings_cmd;
   int size_cmd;
}parseInfo;
```

....

```
parseInfo* parse(char* cmd){
    char* temp = strdup(cmd);
    char* temp_split = strtok(temp," ");
    int i = 0;
    char** strings = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    if(strings == NULL){
        printf("no memory allocated strings parse()\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(temp_split != NULL){
        strings[i++] = strdup(temp_split);
        strings = realloc(strings,i * sizeof(char*));
        if(strings == NULL){
            printf("no memory allocated strings (while) parse()\n");
            exit(1);
        }   
        temp_split = strtok(NULL," ");
    }
    strings[i] = NULL;
    parseInfo* info = (parseInfo*)malloc(sizeof(parseInfo));
    if(info == NULL){
        printf("no memory allocated info parse()\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    info->strings_cmd = strings;
    info->size_cmd = i;
    return info;
}
```

hello guys i get the error:

> realloc(): invalid next size.

and what i try to do is to input a string and split it down into words
for example i input = "Hello World".
and to split it = "Hello" , "World"

but when i pass 4 words i got this error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters the function has a memory leak because in the beginning of the function there is allocated memory

```
parseInfo* parse(char* cmd){
    char* temp = strdup(cmd);
    //...
```

that was not freed.

In this while loop

```
while(temp_split != NULL){
    strings[i++] = strdup(temp_split);
    strings = realloc(strings,i * sizeof(char*));
    if(strings == NULL){
        printf("no memory allocated strings (while) parse()\n");
        exit(1);
    }   
    temp_split = strtok(NULL," ");
```

You need to wirte

```
strings = realloc(strings, ( i + 1 ) * sizeof(char*));
```

to reserve one element for the terminating null pointer used in this statement

```
strings[i] = NULL;
```

And you will need to free the allocated dynamically memory in the beginning of the function like

```
free( temp );

}
```

you are allocating an array of pointers with one less element that it is required.

Answer (score 1):

This line is bad:

```c
        strings = realloc(strings,i * sizeof(char*));
```

This line is resizing the array to `i` elements.
Then, in the next iteration, some value is stored to the `i`-th element of the array (pointed at by) `strings`. The array has only `i` elements (`0` to `i-1`), so this is out-of-range access.

Allocate enough elements to fix:

```c
        strings = realloc(strings,(i + 1) * sizeof(char*));
```

Also note that casting results of `malloc()` family is [considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).